# Session won't be created in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: zend-framework, firefox, session, zend-session, zend-session-namespace

I am working on a purchase system in my assignment and trying to solve the problem by using a session to store data in the process.

Although I'm experiencing a problem in Mozilla Firefox, which cannot for some reason work with the session I have created. There's most likely no doubt that I must have made some kind of mistake.

The process is as follows:

User fills form -> Clicks submit -> [Validation process] -> User reviews confirm page

Here is the relevant code from the controller:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->gatewayForm = new Payment_Form_Gateway;
    $save = $this->validate();

    $this->view->gatewayForm = $save['form'];
    $this->view->alert = $save['alert'];
}

public function validate() {
    # get form
    $form = $this->gatewayForm;
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        # get params            
        $data = $this->_request->getPost();

        # check validate form
        if ($form->isValid($data)) {
            $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('formData'); // name space creation
            $session->data = $data;
            $this->_helper->redirector('confirm', 'gateway', 'payment');
        } else {
            $alert = array('Pay failed');
        }
    $form->populate($data); 
    }
    return array('form' => $form, 'alert' => empty($alert) ? null : $alert );
}

public function confirmAction() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true); // disable std. view

    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('formData');
    $data = $session->data;             
    if(isset($data)) {
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(false);
    } else {
        $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'gateway', 'payment');
    }
}
```

Things go wrong in the confirmAction in Firefox, the session namespace seems to be empty? Although this does not occur in Safari, Chrome, IE etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Firefox and removed config and cache files which did the magic. Problems solved!